# Is theta notation called the average case?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

There are some books which state that theta notation is called the average case while others state that theta is not the average case.
If theta is not the average case then what is called the average case in respect with algorithms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does big Ө notation represent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%d3%a8-notation-represent)

Comment: Asymptotic complexity class notations just express sets of functions, but the author who uses it has to note what it measures (number of operations, memory use, number of messages) and how (all cases, some subset, something amortized, "average case"). Theta notation is just the intersection of big-O and big-Omega (so it's both the lower and upper bound of whatever it measures).

Comment: @VipulPrakash please note that the accepted answer does not really answer the question. You are making an important mistake that is explained in the second answer(@blazs 's answer)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

No, `Θ(g(n))` is not the average case, but you can tell what average case performance is. `Θ` shows order of growth, you can use `Θ` to describe space/time complexity for worst, avarage or best cases. For example Quicksort worst case is `O(n^2)`, while average case performance is `O(NlogN)`

Comment: "You cannot say your algorithm has O(n^2) time complexity and Θ(n)" -- yes, you can.  O() just expresses a (certain kind of) *upper bound*.  For example, finding a given element in an unordered array is both O(n^2) time and Θ(n) time.  (It's also O(n^3) time, and O(42^(7n)) time, but not, for example, O(log n) time.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was thinking about the case when O(n^2) is the best upper bound, then Θ noteation cannot be less function

Comment: Theta notation is used to describe the asymptotic behavior of a class of functions. It can be used for many things including time complexity and memory complexity. It can be used for average case complexity just like for worst case complexity.  This answer does not explain this important mistake in the question.

Comment: Also, Quicksort is Θ(n²) in the worst case and Θ(n Log n) in the average case.

Answer (score 12):

You are confusing two different concepts.

---

The [**average-case time complexity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity) is running time averaged over all possible inputs (under some probability distribution). It is thus a function of the size of the input for a certain algorithm.

The **theta-notation** is just a way of describing a certain type of relationship between two functions. In particular if one function is big-Theta of the other function, this tells us that one grows approximately as fast as the other one.

---

You can use the big-Theta notation to describe the average-case complexity. But you can also use any other notation for this purpose.

If an algorithm has the average-case time complexity of, say, `3*n^2 - 5n + 13`, then it is true that its average-case time complexity is `Theta(n^2)`, `O(n^2)`, and `O(n^3)`. Of these three, `Theta(n^2)` is the most accurate description of its time complexity (but of course not as accurate as the exact expression, which in practice is nearly impossible to get; all we can usually provide is some bounds).

To summarize, the theta-notation (and all other asymptotic notations) allows you to characterize the average-case running time of your algorithm in terms of well-known functions (e.g. it grows approximately as `n^2`).

Comment: To avoid confusion, one shouldn't associate the average-case of an algorithm and the big-theta notation. These are orthogonal concepts. For instance, an algorithm may very well have a worst-case described by a Θ bound or an average-case described by an Ω bound.

Comment: That is precisely what I am saying: that these are two different (independent) concepts.

Answer (score 12):

The O, Ω and Θ notations actually have nothing to do with algorithms best/average/worst cases. They are ways to express the asymptotic behavior of functions, whatever they are.

f(n) = O(g(n)) means that f doesn't grow faster than g. g is an upper bound, tight or not.

f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means that f doesn't grow slower than g. g is a lower bound, tight or not.

f(n) = Θ(g(n)) means that f grows as fast as g. g is a tight bound, both upper and lower.

Then, the best/average/worst running times of an algorithm are functions of the number of elements, and usually have O, Ω, Θ representations.

In the analysis of a particular algorithm, one is often able to derive an O bound for the worst-case, which is tight or not. Also, with more effort, a bound on the average time. Usually you don't care about the best time.

Then in the analysis of a given problem (regardless any particular algorithm that solves it), one can sometimes establish an absolute lower bound on the running time, which is an Ω bound on the best time (tight or not). Lower bounds on the average time are sometimes possible, but highly technical.

Comment: So is it right to think of O as worst, Omega as best and Theta as average running time? Sorry if you have explained this but I guess I didnt quite understand. I mean in terms of if a function is O(n) then this is the worst, or is it the upper bound? Course material I am following suggests O is worst and so on.

Comment: @berimbolo: there is a technical issue here, often bypassed. The running time of an algorithm is usually not a function of n alone. The worst-case running time is a function of n. Big-O denotes an upper bound on a function, and is improperly considered as the "worst case running time". And Big-Θ is not necessarily related to the average case behavior.

Comment: Ok thanks for replying, that does make sense, it would be helpful if literature and course material didnt make this correlation if it is not correct!

Answer (score 2):

I hope to answer the **what, why, and multiple gotchas** of Theta and Average Cases:

### Common Term Mix-up

**Cases** *are not* Big O Notation.

The cases' data are designed by humans to benchmark function performance.

One of these uses can be for determining Big O / Big Omega / Theta time complexity.

A simple quicksort **worst case**, for example, is an array of `n` numbers that jams up our pivot really really bad.

[Wikipedia's quicksort chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) shows that w/e is inside of `n` can make a difference!

| Name | Best Case | Average Case | Worst Case |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Quicksort** | O(n log n) | O(n log n) | O(n<sup>2</sup>) |

[image: Wow!]

Wow!

---

**Big O Notation** represents [*time complexity*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915842/what-is-the-difference-between-time-complexity-and-running-time) when running a function with a nearing infinite amount of `n`.

- `O` (Big O) is **equal (tight) or greater (loose)** to the **most time complexity needed as n -> inf.**
- `Ω` (Big Omega) is **equal (tight) or lesser (loose)** to the **least time complexity needed n -> inf.**
- `Θ` (Theta) is a *tight* bound value when **both `O` and `Ω` tight values are equal in order of magnitude.**

  - [The highest order of magnitude will eventually win after sufficient amount of `n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614585/what-is-constant-factors-and-low-order-term-in-algorithms)

**Each case will have Big O and Big Omega values** (assuming the function doesn't error).

Theta, however, *is not guaranteed.*

### Theta

Take a look at this graph:

[image]

- The line above `f(n)` is a slightly loose Big O approaching `n`.
- The line below `f(n)` is a slightly loose Big Omega approaching `n`.
- Assuming that Big O and Big Omega continue to approach `(n)`, then `Theta(n)`!

  - Note: Although they look far away, they will become closer and closer as `n` heads toward infinity.

#### Loose Values

When someone gives you a Big O value (like Wikipedia), it's *usually* the most tight value.

[A loose boundary value can be expressed as really anything equal to or above its tight value.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62746109/19574391)

- If `Theta(n)`, then:

  - `O(n)` (tight)
  - `O(n^2)` (loose)
  - `O(n^1000)` (loose)

**Warning: People will get frustrated at you giving a loose Big O like this even if you're right!**

Loose boundaries are used mostly for comparisons between other functions.

#### Theta in practice

The existence of (or lack of) Theta becomes more significant in some functions or averages.

Consider [a function that tries to determine a prime number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15277339/19574391):

1. try `n % 2 = 0` -- (which is `O(1)`<sup>*</sup>)
2. try [`for i in range(int(sqrt(n)+1)); n % i = 0`](https://geekflare.com/prime-number-in-python/#geekflare-toc-o-n-algorithm-to-check-for-prime-number-in-python) -- Which is `O(sqrt(n))`

- Best case: `n` are all divisible by 2. `O`, `Ω` are both `(1)`, making `Θ(1)`.
- Worst case: `n` are all prime. `O`, `Ω` are both a slower `(sqrt(n))`, making `Θ(sqrt(n))`.
- "Average" case: `n` are all unsigned integers in a 32bit address.

  - The behavior of this function is `O(sqrt(n))` with `Ω(1)`.
  - Theta *can't be defined* since `O` and `Ω`'s magnitudes don't match at all!

<sup>* This is a basic example, CPU architecture and acceptable numbers range will change the time complexity depending on implementation.</sup>

##### Note: "Average" cases

The top post mentions, and what most people use, is [Average-Case Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity), which (usually) takes all permutations of input and averages the resulting speed to a Big O time.

Take a look at Wikipedia's quicksort, its average time is determined based on [one of three different techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Formal_analysis).

**Average cases still don't eliminate worst case behavior!**

This can be detrimental in real application.

Studying the worst case will give a more accurate representation & prevention strategy.

For instance, quicksort can be substituted for the hybrid introsort, which guarantees worst case `O(n log n)`!

##### Note: performance

Many number of posts, particularly in higher-level languages like Python, will be confused as to why different `O(n log n)` sorting algorithms finish seconds or even minutes apart from each other.

One thing to consider is *input size* and ***constant factor***. Big O notation assumes `n` is a nearly infinite finite number, meaning something like [`O(6n * log n + 6n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22614799/19574391) converges into `O(n log n)` time after a massive amount of `n` are loaded in.

**However,** runtime for finite amounts of `n` can certainly be impacted by something like `O(6n * log n + 6n)` despite turning into `O(n log n)` at some point! [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935203/right-way-to-discuss-computational-complexity-for-small-n)

Quicksort happens to be one such sufferer, [where size of `n` has a great impact on which internal method is quicker](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/quick-sort-randomized-pivot-vs-median-of-3-ninther-pivot-vs-uniform-shuffle-o), despite all of them being `O(n log n)`!

Here are other variables that will impact run time of similar Big O functions:

- Code implementation
- Real world input
- Type of data
- Compiler optimizations
- Computer architecture
- Available resources
- Software bugs
- Human error

Big O and average cases are a great starting place to consider speed at large `n` scale (or whatever else you may be measuring), but testing your implementation as best as possible is still vital, especially at small scale!

Answer (score -2):

As **'O'** (Big-Oh) is used to defined for Worst case i.e. Upper bound for the problem.
And, Ω is used to define for the Best Case i.e. Lower bound for the problem.
Same way, Θ is used to defined anything between Upper bound and lower bound.

As upper bound and lower bound will not occur frequently. So, While running our algorithm most of the time we'll come to the scenarios in between of these two extream points.
So, We Calculate the Average time taken by the algorithm and we denote it by Θ notation.

But, It doesn't mean that Worst case and Average case complexity for the Algorithm will never same.
It may same or may not be.

Becuase there could be an algorithm which is running in the best case for a particular input and other than that input it taking the same time for rest of the inputs.
In such case, Avg & Worst case complexities would be same.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You are correct, this answer is wrong. Also \Omega is not used to define the best case as it is stated. \Omega gives an asymptotic lower bound on a function so it gives a lower bound on the growth of the worst case runtime per input length which could be completely different to the best case runtime.
Example: Travelling salesman is in \Omega(1) but that does not mean that there is an algorithm/input combination which can really do it that fast.

Comment: @AEF Omega is used denote Best case and Big oh is used to denote Worst case. 

I would suggest you to please take look into Cormen.

Comment: I have a master's degree in mathematics, I know what I am talking about when it comes to asyptotic behaviour of functions ;) You can also read  the other answers and comments in this thread: Many of them confirm what I have said.