# Find runtime (number of operations of function) and calculate Big O

Tags: python, time-complexity

For the python function given below, I have to find the number of Operations and Big O.

```
def no_odd_number(list_nums):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_nums):
        num = list_nums[i]
        if num % 2 != 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

From my calculation, the number of operations is `4 + 3n` but I'm not sure as I don't know how to deal with `if...else` statements.

I am also given options to choose the correct Big O from, from my calculation, I think it should be `d. O(n)` but I'm not sure. Help please!

```
a. O(n^2)

b. O(1)

c. O(log n)

d. O(n)

e. None of these
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O notation typically considers the worst case scenario. The function you have is pretty simple, but the early return seems to complicate things. However, since we care about the worst case you can ignore the `if` block. The worst case will be one where you don't return early. It would be a list like `[2,4,6,8]`, which would run the loop four times.

Now, look at the things inside the while loop, with the above in mind. It doesn't matter how big `list_nums` is: inside the loop you just increment `i` and lookup something in a list. Both of those are constant time operations that are the same regardless of how large `list_nums` is.

The number of times you do this loop is the length of `list_nums`. This means as `list_nums` grows, the number of operations grows at the same rate. That makes this `O(n)` as you suspect.

Comment: “Big O notation considers the worst case scenario.” — Where does this come from? I keep seeing this on Stack Overflow, but the big O notation can of course also be used to analyse expected/average case behaviour (the expected runtime of generic quicksort is conventionally given as O(n·logn)), and in principle (though much rarer) even best-case behaviour.

Comment: That's a fair question @KonradRudolph. I think it's convention that when something like average case is not asked for we talk about the ceiling. For instance the best case in the above is constant time with a list that starts with an odd number, but that doesn't explain the complexity of the function. Average case is still O(n) (but that itself make assumptions about the distribution of input). On the other hand something like Quicksort is often described in terms of complexity of the average case, with a note the worst case is O(n2).

Comment: Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value.  Computer science uses the Big O }, Big Theta Θ, and Big Omega notations to describe the Max, mean, and min performance see .[Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

Comment: That's conflating two different things @itprorh66. The asymptotic complexity in the best or average case is not equivalent to Big Theta or Big Omega. There's a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138236/is-theta-notation-called-the-average-case)

Comment: Big O is the upper bound, while Omega is the lower bound. Theta requires both Big O and 
Omega, so that's why it's referred to as a tight bound (it must be both the upper and lower 
bound). For example, an algorithm taking Omega(n log n) takes at least n log n time but has no 
upper limit. An algorithm taking Theta(n log n) is far preferential since it takes AT LEAST n log 
n (Omega n log n) and NO MORE THAN n log n (Big O n log n).

Comment: That's great but that's not what we are talking about when comparing the best case (i.e. input like `[1, 2, 3]` which returns in constant time) and worst case `[2, 4, 6]` which is linear.  If you think about it, defining Omega in terms of input would mean pretty much *all*  algorithms would have Big Omega of constant time because you could always consider the empty input as the lower bound. That of course makes no sense and makes Big Omega meaningless.

Comment: With random numbers, average time is O(1).

Comment: Yeah, that's an interesting insight @KellyBundy that I didn't consider in my first comment above.